# How cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) works?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a video with this information:

```
fps = 29.971695558454563
number of frames = 26983
duration (S) = 900.2827333333333
duration (M:S) = 15:0.28273333333333994
```

My question is: Why when i use:

```
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 30)
```

The :

```
cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
```

Return :

```
0.5
```

It shouldnt be something close to 1000 mls?

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 30)
print('FPS VIDEO',fps)
print('Mils',cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))
timestamp = get_hms(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))


FPS VIDEO 29.971695558454563
Mils 0.5
hora 0:00:00.000500

def get_hms(millis):
    hms = timedelta(milliseconds=millis)
    print('hora',hms)
    return hms
```

Comment: **seeking** is generally broken in OpenCV, and generally hard on arbitrary files, unless you're willing to analyze the entire file first. don't rely on it. it may work on some files, but not others.

Answer (score 2):

Well it is just a bug:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15749

It will just work if you use :

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

Before call :

```
print('Mils',cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))
```

Comment: Dont think it's a bug. For some sources trying to read the timestamp of the next (yet unknown) frame doesnt make much sense, because the time is only known after the frame is present.